# Scala XML, Get nodes where parent has attribute value match

Tags: xml, scala, xpath

Any way to simplify the following? or reduce the boilerplate code with another function?

```
scala> val ns = <foo><bar id="1"><tag>one</tag><tag>uno</tag></bar><bar id="2"><tag>two</tag><tag>dos</tag></bar></foo>
ns: scala.xml.Elem = <foo><bar id="1"><tag>one</tag><tag>uno</tag></bar><bar id="2"><tag>two</tag><tag>dos</tag></bar></foo>

scala> (ns \\ "bar" filterNot{_ \\ "@id"  find { _.text == "1" } isEmpty}) \\ "tag"
res0: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<tag>one</tag>, <tag>uno</tag>)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I could only find a minor improvement, the `find`/`isEmpty` test can be replaced with `exists`:

```
(ns \\ "bar" filter { _ \\ "@id" exists (_.text == "1") }) \\ "tag"
```

**Edit after clarifying comment:**

That's a really nice idea! Try this for size:

```
import xml._

implicit def richNodeSeq(ns: NodeSeq) = new {

  def \@(attribMatch: (String, String => Boolean)): NodeSeq =
    ns filter { _ \\ ("@" + attribMatch._1) exists (s => attribMatch._2(s.text)) }

}

ns \\ "bar" \@ ("id", _ == "1") \\ "tag"
```

I used a predicate instead of hard-coding the attribute value comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement. What I'm really looking for is a way to create a selector for filter { _ \\ "@id" exists (_.text  == "1") })   then it looks something like (x \\ "bar" \@ ("@id","1") \\ "tag"

Comment: I like your idea. I have edited my answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to define implicit class:

```
   object XmlE {
    implicit class XmlE(val xml: NodeSeq) extends AnyVal {
         def \@(attr: (String, String => Boolean)): NodeSeq = {
             xml filter {
                _ \ ("@" + attr._1) exists (s => attr._2(s.text))
                         }
                    }
            }
   }
```

Then use it from another class :

```
import XmlE._
.....
```