# Simple Xpath query in scala

Tags: xml, scala, xpath

I'm trying to run a XPath query with scala and it doesn't seem to work. 
My Xml looks like ( simplified):

```
<application>
  <process type="output" size ="23"> 
     <channel offset="0"/>
      ....
     <channel offset="4"/>
  </process>
  <process type="input" size ="16"> 
     <channel offset="20"/>
      ....
     <channel offset="24"/>
  </process>
</application>
```

I want to retrieve the `process` with the `input` attribute and for that i use this XPath query:

```
//process[@type='input']
```

This should work, i verified it with [xpathtester](http://www.xpathtester.com/test)
Now, my scala code looks like:

```
import scala.xml._
val x = XML.loadFile("file.xml")

val process = (x \\ "process[@type='input']")  // will return empty NodeSeq() !!!
```

The `process` ends up empty, it does't capture what I want. I worked it around like this:

```
val process = (x \\ "process" filter( _ \"@type" contains Text("input")))
```

which is much uglier. Any known reason why my original query shouldn't work?

Comment: There is no `ProcessImage` element in your example. Can you match up your sample code to your description? Also, please don't forget to mention any XML namespaces your document uses.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it already. There are no namespaces used

Comment: http://www.oo-systemutvecklare.se/scala-for-java-developers/scala-xml-java-xpath-implicit-conversions/ suggests that your "ugly" try is actually pretty much as close as you can get.

Comment: Scala xpath https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.xpath

Answer (score 4):

"XPath" should not be used to describe what the Scala standard library supports. XPath is a full-fledged expression language, with so far two final versions and a third in the works:

- [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) from 1999
- [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) from 2007 (2nd edition 2010)
- [XPath 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/) from 2013 (candidate recommendation)

At best you could say that Scala has a very small subset of XPath-inspired operations. So you can't expect to take XPath expressions and directly paste them to Scala without doing a bit more work.

Third-party libraries can give you better support for actual XPath expressions, including:

- [Scales Xml](https://github.com/chris-twiner/scalesXml)

  - Scala library
  - "provides a far more XPath like experience than the normal Scala XML, Paths look like XPaths and work like them too (with many of the same functions and axes)"
  - it's still not actual XPath if I understand well
  - designed to integrate well with Scala
- [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/)

  - Java library
  - open source
  - complete and conformant support for XPath 2 (and XSLT 2)
  - has an XPath API which works on DOM and other data models, but no specific Scala support at this time

Comment: Saying "the best" about Saxon seems a bit arbitrary to me. There are other os XQuery (XPath being a subset of XQuery) processors out there (e.g. eXist and BaseX), which are also very good and conformant. I don't see in why they should be worse than BaseX or what even measures "the best".

Comment: That adjective just reflects my ignorance of BaseX. (I know and use eXist, but wouldn't mention it here as it's not designed to be used as an independent XPath implementation.) Are you saying that BaseX could be used as an XPath evaluator independently of the database? Any docs on this?

Comment: Sure, but there is no special doc for this as it is simply standard for the processor. You can e.g. simply run `basex -q"YOUR_QUERY". You can also use an input file to work on. Or you can use the GUI, of course. You can use BaseX simply as an XQuery processor, no need to use the database.

Comment: It's great to know if BaseX can be run from the command line, but the original question was related to how to use XPath from Scala, or at least that's how I interpreted it. Saxon has an XPath API which you can call from Java/Scala. It would be interesting if you could do the same from BaseX.

Comment: There is a separate Scala client to communicate with a BaseX server instance: https://github.com/delving/basex-scala-client. Also, as BaseX is written in Java I guess you can access the library in some way (I have no experience in Scala), certainly you can do it from Java. Java examples can be found at https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Java_Examples

Comment: Ok thanks. What's still a bit unclear is whether you can just run the BaseX engine on a plain DOM in memory from Java (Scala interoperates with Java so it's pretty much the same). Do you know if that's the case?

Comment: You can define an external context and bind the context from Java/Scala.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that would be to use [kantan.xpath](http://nrinaudo.github.io/kantan.xpath/):

```
import kantan.xpath._
import kantan.xpath.implicits._

val input = """
     | <application>
     |   <process type="output" size ="23">
     |      <channel offset="0"/>
     |      <channel offset="4"/>
     |   </process>
     |   <process type="input" size ="16">
     |      <channel offset="20"/>
     |      <channel offset="24"/>
     |   </process>
     | </application>
     | """.stripMargin

val inputs = input.evalXPath[List[Node]](xp"//process[@type='input']")
```

This yields a `List[Node]`, but you could retrieve values with more interesting types - the list of channel offsets, for example:

```
input.evalXPath[List[Int]](xp"//process[@type='input']/channel/@offset")
// This yields Success(List(20, 24))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the scala xml implementation is not able to process such complicated XPath queries. However it's not difficult to create a small rich wrapper to reduce clutter, e.g. take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574862/scala-xml-get-nodes-where-parent-has-attribute-value-match). With the suggested wrapper you can solve your problem like so:

```
x \\ "process" \@ ("type", _ == "input")
```

Comment: Saw that one, but since the thread's a couple years old I'm hoping there might be a better way now with scala 2.10

Comment: I wouldn't hold my breath for big improvements in this respect until XML support becomes pluggable in Scala. My understanding is that the current implementation is considered too broken to fix.