# Xpath processing using Scala

Tags: xml, scala, xpath

I am new to Scala and trying to understand the capability of Scala with regards to xml processing using xpaths.

Going though [Simple Xpath query in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743252/simple-xpath-query-in-scala) it appears that if I try to use an xpath to extract value from an xml like - **elem \\ "/BCXYZ/abc/def**" - using Scala, it wont work.

I can though use something like **elem \\ "BCXYZ" \ "abc" \ "def"** where **elem** is a scala.xml.Elem object (representing the xml from which I want to extract the xpath value).

Can someone confirm please.

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer there says, Scala XML does not have XPath built-in. It has something that looks like XPath for very simple path extraction, and,  yes, it won't work the way you want.

There are at least two other XML libraries for Scala, [one of which](https://github.com/chris-twiner/scalesXml) has full XPath support.

Answer (score 1):

I dislike the standard library's version of XML. If you're trying to execute XPath expressions, may I suggest [kantan.xpath](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.xpath)?

It lets you write things like:

```
import kantan.xpath.ops._

new java.io.File("input.xml").evalXPath[List[Int]]("//@id")
```

This will do what you expect: parse `input.xml` as an XML document, look for all elements that have an `id` attribute and extract that attribute as an `Int`, storing all values in a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Given an XML like

```
 <BCXYZ>
    <abc>
        <def>
            text
        </def>
    </abc>
</BCXYZ>
```

The query would work as stated

```
scala> elem \\ "BCXYZ" \ "abc" \ "def"
res20: scala.xml.NodeSeq = 
NodeSeq(<def>
text
</def>)
```